# Check if Sync is Enabled within Android App

Tags: android, synchronization

Is there a way to check, programmatically within my Android app, whether a particular setting under Settings > Accounts and Sync > Data & Synchronization is enabled or not?

Is there a way to check if the general sync settings are enabled?

Thanks!

---

If it helps to know "why," I'm currently rolling my own sync functionality (not using SyncAdapter). However, if possible I'd like to have my sync service listed under Data & Synchronization. Right now I'm planning to hack a dummy sync service that does nothing and have my app's sync service query whether or not the dummy sync service is enabled. That will tell me whether to sync or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check whether sync is enable or not with the help of below code and [this **Document**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#isSyncActive%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(YourActivity.this);
Account account = am.getAccountsByType(Const.ACCOUNT_TYPE)[0];
  if(ContentResolver.isSyncActive(account, DataProvider.AUTHORITY){
     // sync is enable
  }
```

You can also set enable/disable programmatically with the help of this `ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically` and `ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically`

**Update** :

isSyncActive returns true if there is currently a sync operation for the given account or authority in the pending list, or actively being processed.

Comment: Nice. Is there a way that I can "listen" to when the setting is changed in the Data & Synchronization menu? (Maybe there's some kind of broadcast I can receive?)

Comment: The documentation of "isSyncActive" says: "Returns true if *there is currently a sync* operation for the given account or authority in the pending list, or actively being processed." --- So as soon as the sync operation for a given account is over, it will return false even though syncing is enabled for that account.

Comment: as @NobuGames pointed out, this is not the answer to the question.

Comment: Where does Const.ACCOUNT_TYPE come from? and where does DataProvider.AUTHORITY come from?

Answer (score 26):

To know if a sync is enabled (and not active as [rajpara's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11253155/775894) do), use this:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(YourActivity.this);
Account account = am.getAccountsByType(YOUR_ACCOUNT_TYPE)[0];
boolean isYourAccountSyncEnabled = ContentResolver.getSyncAutomatically(account, DataProvider.AUTHORITY);
boolean isMasterSyncEnabled = ContentResolver.getMasterSyncAutomatically();
```

The "master" sync status is the global sync switch the user can use to disable all sync on his phone. If the master sync is off, your account won't sync, even if your account sync status tells that it's enabled.

As @HiB mentionned, the `android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS` permission is needed to access the sync status. `android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS` is needed to enable/disable it.

You also need `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` to get the accounts, as MeetM mentionned.

Comment: `android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS` and `android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS` needed

Comment: Are you sure about the `WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS` one?

Comment: for writing the value... so you are right here is not necessary to mention

Comment: Also `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` is required. Although its obvious, but for anyone like me :)

Comment: The android documentation seems to be completely misleading here as it only talks about a network tickle https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getSyncAutomatically(android.accounts.Account, java.lang.String)

Comment: Where does YOUR_ACCOUNT_TYPE come from? and where does DataProvider.AUTHORITY come from?

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean isEnabled = ContentResolver.getSyncAutomatically(account, MyProvider);
if(isEnabled)
{
...do something
}
```

Works for me

Comment: Where does account and MyProvider come from?

Comment: AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(YourActivity.this);
Account account = am.getAccountsByType(Const.ACCOUNT_TYPE)[0];
Provider you must be created by yourself